# How to create array of strings in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am using VueJS and Vuetify to create a modal that can accept some strings in the text field. Now what i want to do is to push the input string inside an array `on click`. So let's say if i input something and click create the resultant array is `['inputValue1']` but if i add another value by separating with a comma, the resultant array should be `['inputValue1', 'inputValue2']` instead i am getting it as `['inputValue1', 'inputValue1' 'inputValue2']`. So the new value should be pushed to the new index instead of adding it with the last value.

Here is a [demo](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/GRppgxB)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false,
      inputValue: "",
      stringArray: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    createArray() {
      if (this.inputValue !== "") {
        this.stringArray.push(this.inputValue);
        console.log(this.stringArray);
      }
    },
    closeDialog() {
      this.dialog = false;
      this.inputValue = "";
      this.stringArray = [];
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-layout justify-center>
      <v-flex>
        <v-btn color="primary" @click="dialog=!dialog"> Click Me </v-btn>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" width=350>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title primary-title>
          Create Array
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          <span class="title">How to create Array of Strings </span>
          <v-layout justify-center>
            <v-flex xs11>
              <v-text-field v-model="inputValue"></v-text-field>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions class="mt-5">
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn @click="closeDialog">CLOSE</v-btn>
          <v-btn @click="createArray" :disabled="this.inputValue === ''" color="primary">CREATE</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Also `on Cancel` how can i set the input value and the array to an empty string and an empty array respectively. Thank You. I asked it yesterday but had to delete since i wasn't able to figure out the exact issue.

Comment: Not sure what's your problem, the `createArray` method adds strings to the array correctly. You don't have it attached to any click event though

Comment: oops, good catch. Fixed it. lol that fixed the issue.

Comment: @Eggon Thank you so much!! sometimes i guess that's all you need.

Comment: if you add that as an answer, i'll gladly accept it.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: @Eggon Quick help, it seems like the cancel is not setting the inputValue to an empty string? If i close the modal and check the dev tools, the inputValue is still persistent.

Comment: The code is fine. It also works for me. If you close and open again - no value is in the input.

Comment: @Eggon Since i have the vue dev tools, it shows the value still being assigned.

Comment: Are you sure that's just not past value in deev tools. Have you tried refreshing (there's a trefresh option in vue's dev tools)? Certainly for vuex VDT don't show current values until refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `createArray' method is not attached to any click event. Other than that the code is correct. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should clear the inputValue after the value is pushed to the array like this:

```
methods: {
createArray() {
  if (this.inputValue !== "") {
    this.stringArray.push(this.inputValue);
    this.inputValue = '';
    console.log(this.stringArray);
  } else {
  console.log('The inputValue is empty')
 }
},
closeDialog() {
  this.dialog = false;
  this.inputValue = "";
  this.stringArray = []
}
}
 });
```

Comment: yup applied this as well. Thank you!!